# Blackberry Development Platforms

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, windows-mobile, blackberry, mobile

I was wondering about the pros and cons on the different Blackberry development environments. I am trying to decide whether to use Visual Studio or Eclipse.

Your thoughts are appreciated

Tony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio is a RAD development tool, easy to throw together some code and get a few screens together but you don't get much control over what's happening and can't customize it easily.

I much prefer Eclipse as you can access the [RIM API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/index.html) and you have much more control over what's happening, e.g. create your own controls, customise menus and access much more functionality within the handset.

On the various forums, http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/ or http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board?board.id=java_dev for example, you get much better support for Java (Eclipse or JDE).

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse because the initial setup for Blackberry development & the howto videos from RIM assumes that you are using Eclipse.  Since you need the Blackberry JRE and will be testing with the blackberry simulator, using Eclipse will be the most hassle free. Visual Studio is beautiful but not free (unless you are student and visit Microsoft's Dreamspark website)